# C# LINQ to objects query to change the field value based on List

Tags: c#-4.0, linq-to-objects

I have the follwing objects

```
 objItem (id,name,qty)  - list<items>
 objSel(selId)      - list<int>
```

objSel.selId is the selected item id of objItem.

How to write the LINQ query to change item qty to 0 if the items are not selected and return objItem.

Comment: I've written an answer, but if it's not what you're looking for, please clarify the question more. Ideally, show real code rather than pseudo-code.

Comment: Jon, I thought we can use LINQ to both filter and change the field value. If this is the best way to do this, i'll go with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pseudo-code is quite confusing, but I *suspect* you want something like:

```
List<Item> items = ...;
List<int> selectedIds = ...;

foreach (var item in items.Where(x => !selectedIds.Contains(x.Id)))
{
    item.Quantity = 0; // Property name adjusted for readability and convention
}
```

For more efficiently, use `HashSet<int>` for the selected IDs instead.

Note that it's not the LINQ *query* which performs the change - the query just gives the items which require changing. While you *can* abuse LINQ to change data, it's a bad idea to do so. The clue is in the word "query" - it's about asking a question. What you do with the answer to that question is a different matter.

Comment: Jon, I thought we can use LINQ to both filter and change the field value. If this is the best way to do this, i'll go with this. Thanks.

Comment: @Wilz: You *can*, but that's not what it's designed for - you have to fight against LINQ to do that, basically. Now if you were to redesign so that you weren't changing existing objects, but creating new objects based on the existing ones and some condition, that's a different matter.